# Reactjs Router version 5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Using `react-router@5` with class component with router match.

```javascript
import React, { lazy } from "react";
import { Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { history } from "./history";
import Header from "../src/assests/components/header";
import Footer from "../src/assests/components/Footer";

const Routers = [
  { path: '/', component: "./views/home", exact: true },

  { path: '/login',                                    component: "./views/login", fullLayout: true, hideFooter: true },
  { path: '/register',                                 component: "./views/login", fullLayout: true, hideFooter: true },
  { path: '/mutual-fund/deskpay',                      component: "./views/deskpay", fullLayout: true, hideFooter: true },
  { path: '/calculator/sip-calculator',                component: "./views/calculator/sip_calculator.js" },
  { path: '/calculator/lumpsum-calculator',            component: "./views/calculator/lumpsum_calculator.js" },
  { path: '/calculator/sip-reverse-calculator',        component: "./views/calculator/sip_reverse_calculator.js" },
  { path: '/calculator/cagr-calculator',               component: "./views/calculator/cagr-calculator.js" },
  { path: '/calculator/xirr-mutual-fund-calculator',   component: "./views/calculator/xirr-calculator" },
  { path: '/calculator/exit-load-calculator',          component: "./views/calculator/exit-load-calculator" },
  { path: '/calculator/reverse-lumpsum-calculator',    component: "./views/calculator/lumpsum-reverse-calculator" },
  { path: '/calculator/stepup-sip-calculator',         component: "./views/calculator/sip-stepup-calculator" },
  { path: '/calculator/sip-calculator-with-inflation', component: "./views/calculator/sip-calculator-with-inflanation.js" },
  { path: '/calculator/capital-gain-calculator',       component: "./views/calculator/capital-gain-calculator" },
  { path: '/calculator',                               component: "./views/calculator/index.js" },
  { path: '/calculator/:amcName',                      component: "./views/amc-calculator" },
  { path: '*',                                         component: "./views/error/404" },
  { path: '/500',                                      component: "./views/error/500" },
]

class AppRouter extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={history}>
        <Switch>
          {Routers.map(({ path, component: C, fullLayout, hideFooter, exact, key }) => {
            var Component = lazy(() => import(`${C}`))
            return (
              <Route
                key={key}
                path={path}
                exact={exact}
                render={(props) => {
                  console.log(props)
                  return (
                    <React.Fragment>
                      {fullLayout ? "" : <Header />}
                      <Component {...props}/> 
                      {hideFooter ? "" : <Footer/>}
                    </React.Fragment>
                  );
                }}
              />
            )
          })}
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default AppRouter;
```

Actually this is my code when I change place `{ path: '/calculator/:amcName', component: "./views/amc-calculator" ,}`, from json to set before sip calculator it doesn't render remaining calculator.

Comment: What is the issue? What needs to be fixed? You might need to actually share a relevant [mcve] so we can see what issue(s) any code may have. Try to include the router and routes, and the specific components using the `withRouter` HOC that are having a problem accessing the route props, and clarify in greater detail the specific issue you are trying to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

> when I change place `{ path: '/calculator/:amcName', component: "./views/amc-calculator" ,}`, from json to set before sip calculator
> it doesn't render remaining calculator.

If I'm understanding your comment/question correctly here you are asking about why placing the `"/calculator/:amcName"` route before the `"/calculator/sip-calculator"` route causes the rest of the `"/calculator/*"` routes to not be matched and rendered.

Within the `Switch` component route path order and specificity matters. The `Switch` component "renders the ***first*** child `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` that matches the location." If the current URL path is `"/calculator/sip-calculator"` or `"/calculator/xirr-mutual-fund-calculator"` or *any other* `"/calculator/*"` and the first `"/calculator/*"` route path is `"/calculator/:amcName"`, then `"/calculator/:amcName"` will be the route that is matched and its component will be rendered.

While you *could* sprinkle the `exact` prop all over the code, there's almost no need for it if you order your routes correctly in ***inverse*** order of path specificity, from ***more*** specific paths to ***less*** specific paths. Within the `"/calculator"` root route `"/calculator/sip-calculator"` etc. is more specific than `"/calculator/:amcName"` is more specific than `"/calculator"`.

Example:

```
const routes = [
  // More specific paths than "/"
  { path: '/login', component: "./views/login", fullLayout: true, hideFooter: true },
  { path: '/register', component: "./views/login", fullLayout: true, hideFooter: true },
  { path: '/mutual-fund/deskpay', component: "./views/deskpay", fullLayout: true, hideFooter: true },

  // More specific "/calculator/..." route paths
  { path: '/calculator/sip-calculator', component: "./views/calculator/sip_calculator.js" },
  { path: '/calculator/lumpsum-calculator', component: "./views/calculator/lumpsum_calculator.js" },
  { path: '/calculator/sip-reverse-calculator', component: "./views/calculator/sip_reverse_calculator.js" },
  { path: '/calculator/cagr-calculator', component: "./views/calculator/cagr-calculator.js" },
  { path: '/calculator/xirr-mutual-fund-calculator', component: "./views/calculator/xirr-calculator" },
  { path: '/calculator/exit-load-calculator', component: "./views/calculator/exit-load-calculator" },
  { path: '/calculator/reverse-lumpsum-calculator', component: "./views/calculator/lumpsum-reverse-calculator" },
  { path: '/calculator/stepup-sip-calculator', component: "./views/calculator/sip-stepup-calculator" },
  { path: '/calculator/sip-calculator-with-inflation', component: "./views/calculator/sip-calculator-with-inflanation.js" },
  { path: '/calculator/capital-gain-calculator', component: "./views/calculator/capital-gain-calculator" },

  // Less specific "/calculator/*" path
  { path: '/calculator/:amcName', component: "./views/amc-calculator" },

  // Least specific "/calculator" path
  { path: '/calculator', component: "./views/calculator/index.js" },

  { path: '/500', component: "./views/error/500" },

  // Least specific known path, exact is ok here
  { path: '/', component: "./views/home", exact: true },

  // Least specific unknown path, catches anything not handled above
  { path: '*', component: "./views/error/404" },
];
```

Comment: If i use router dynamically wherever put url, here i change '/calculator/:amcName' before the sip calculator,  sip calculator only render remaining calculator not render it redirect to calcutor page

Comment: @manimk Sorry, I'm having trouble trying to understand what your comment means. Can you clarify?

Comment: if i placed '/calculator/amcName' url wherever it's not working. It Redirect to calculator home page.

Comment: @manimk What do you mean by "placed '/calculator/amcName'` url wherever"? What would be redirecting here? You shouldn't be placing the routes "wherever" as this might be part of the reason they aren't matching as you expect. It might be clearer if you could create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces the routing issue you are describing.